# Increment another cell value in excel using the same cell again and again

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a excel data in a cell. Lets call it CELL A5.

I have another cell lets say B5.

I want that whatever value I will provide in B5 it will get incremented in A5 everytime I enter value in B5. FOR EXAMPLE when I enter 10 A5 value will be 10 at first. NExt time when I enter value 5 in B5 A5 will increment to 15.

Kindly let me know how to acheive that. (Will a button and vb script necessart to implement this)

Comment: Maybe handle the [Worksheet.Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this can be done with a formula but in vba it's very simple. Save this sub in your worksheet object:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        If Target.Address = "$A$5" Then
                Dim arr
                arr = Range("A5:B5").Value2
                Range("B5").Value2 = arr(1, 1) + arr(1, 2)
        End If
    End Sub
```